# WTD, MTD, YTD working hours of each employee with different timestamps for each day using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is a sample data. I need to calculate working hours in DAX.

Working hours for one day = Last Timestamp of the day - First Timestamp of the day
It is easy to calculate for one day but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate total working hours WTD, MTD, YTD.

Every day timestamps are different and we want working hours for each Worker(Name) separately. Please guide. I can share the actual data as well if anybody requires.

[image]

Comment: [Follow this to provide sample data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I asked the question on Power BI community and got the answer from there. We have to use the summarize function.

```
[Total Man-Hours] =
24 * SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table,
        Table[Name],
        Table[Date]
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table[Timestamp] ) - MIN( Table[Timestamp] )
    )
)
```